# Tomcat: listening to server lifecyle events from within a webapp

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to listen to tomcat lifecycle events in my webapp. I tried following code

```
try {
    MBeanServer mBeanServer = MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null).get(0);
    ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Catalina", "type", "Server");
    Server server = (Server) mBeanServer.getAttribute(name, "managedResource");
    server.addLifecycleListener(new LifecycleListener() {
        @Override
        public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event) {
            logger.info("lifecycle listener called. event: " + event.getType());
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    //log error
}
```

I can successfully get the `Server` object and register for lifecyle events, but the code doesn't receive any lifecycle events.

I checked the status of all services and connectors in the `Server` object by iterating through them and there are components which are in `STARTING` state. So, I should receive the `STARTED` event of them.

Dose anyone know what is wrong?